# Usage of 期待してくれる in a romantic context

Tags: reading-comprehension, giving-and-receiving

Context: The two characters are on  a date and the guy invites the girl to his home and she says "yes." Upon hearing her "yes" the guy says this

> 期待してくれるって思っていいの?

Her answer is

> 。。。してたよ。期待。昨日からずっと.

I'm struggling to understand the 期待してくれる here.  I guess he's saying "is it fine to think you had expectations for me?"  Like you were expecting me to make a move?

Comment: Basically your understanding is correct, but *what* is expected is just unclear from the provided context.

Comment: Wasn't it 期待してくれ**て**る by any chance?

Comment: @aguijonazo I don't see an issue with it being 期待してくれる, considering してた as an answer. Just that the OP's interpretation is slightly off.

Comment: @shinku - I don't see how the answer makes the question any more likely to be asking what the girl **will** do in the future.

Comment: you are right, it was してくれてる