# Usage of 誰が in a sentence like this one

Tags: particle-が, questions

Context: The character A made B favorite's food, B is sorta tsundere and didn't want to eat this. So after B takes a bite, A said this:

はは……。好きものめ。銜えただけで、顔がとろけているぞ

"Haha, you really love it. Just by taking a bite, your face is melting.

And then there is B's answer:

ん……。誰がこんな風にしたんだよ

I'm confused by B answer. Is he saying it "who would do something like that?" or is it more "Well, whose fault it is (you who made the food) that I'm acting like this?"

Answer (score 2):

Like [one of your previous questions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/102592/45489), your understanding is basically fine. 誰が is just *who* used as a rhetoric question.

In the sentence, the object of した is omitted, but most probably it's the speaker ('me'). Thus it means *Who made me like this?*, where *this* referring to the speaker making a 'melting face' when having a bite. It has a blaming tone, so it can be understood as "Well, whose fault it is (you who made the food) that I'm acting like this?" except the 'who made the food' part. About what exactly B is kind of blaming A is unclear from the provided text.

To make the full sense of the sentence is more about understanding the *scene* than the sentence.